# Jacoco execution data does not match for Hilt classes

Tags: android, jacoco, dagger-hilt

Running jacoco coverage reports for my android app results in:

```
[ant:jacocoReport] Execution data for class de/abc/def/MyApplication does not match.
```

-> The coverage reports 0%

The android app uses Hilt and requires an Application class

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class MyApplication : Application()
```

This is most likely related because

1. I do not see any issue in another file and
2. the MyApplication is only these 2 lines
3. running the coverage without the @HiltAndroidApp works without any issue

Any solution on how to fix it?
I thought about somehow removing the annotation before any tag, but this must have been encountered by the Hilt devs during their testing I believe

(AGP 7.2.1, Gradle 7.4.2, jacoco 0.8.10)

Answer (score 0):

In the latest versions of JaCoCo, 8.7 and above, you can generate reports for both **androidTestCoverage** and **unitTestCoverage** in Android projects. These reports are created separately in the reports folder, where you can find distinct **reports.xml** files for each type of coverage.

**Sonar changes**

```
// Define multiple paths in a list
def xmlReportPaths = ['/path/to/first/report.xml','/path/to/second/report.xml']

// Convert the list to a comma-separated string
def xmlReportPathString = xmlReportPaths.join(',')
```

// Set the property in your script or configuration
// For example, in a Gradle build script:

```
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property 'sonar.xmlReportPaths', xmlReportPathString
    }
}
```

After the changes run the sonar command.
**gradlew sonarqube**

Now you can see all covered files and combined report.
It will works.